# WiFi stopped working (DISABLED) in Ubuntu 18.04 on ThinkPad P70

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, intel-wireless, additional-drivers

I performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 the other day and WiFi worked perfectly during the install as well as after the install. But once I rebooted a day or two later, WiFi from the system bar reports that it is on (it shows "turn off") but no networks are found that I can select from (usually there are  2 or 3 there).

So yesterday I updated to the latest kernel v4.17.5 and rebooted, and once I reinstalled my Nvidia-396 drivers, WiFi was back working properly. Today after rebooting, WiFi is gone again with no networks found.

Here is the result of rfkill list all

> rfkill list all

```
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and here is the relevant network controller entry from lspci -nnk

> lspci -nnk

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0130]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

and finally, here is the result of lshw -C network which shows my WiFI as DISABLED. I have not problems hardwiring to the ethernet. Also, when I boot Windows 10, the WiFi works perfectly, it's just Ubuntu 18.04. Ubuntu 16.04 which I was using for the last 2 years never had an issue with the WiFi

> lshw -C network

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 3a
       serial: a4:34:d9:ec:72:96
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.17.5-041705-generic firmware=36.e91976c0.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:154 memory:d4d00000-d4d01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 31
       serial: 50:7b:9d:9e:37:59
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.8-3 ip=192.168.2.43 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:150 memory:d5900000-d591ffff
```

Here is the dmesg output

> dmesg | grep iwlwifi

```
[   11.428027] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   11.438467] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 36.e91976c0.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   11.466297] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208
[   11.564695] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: a4:34:d9:ec:72:96
[   12.640474] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
```

I did reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 a couple of times when I first discovered this issue and the WiFi always works during the install, but not after I install all my usual applications and then reboot. None of the apps I install touch the WiFI settings as far as I know; they are all just apps for developing Android and Java apps.

Also, one the main differences I've noticed from 16.04 to 18.04 is that the software updater Additional Drivers page used to have an additional network driver that I think I may have had selected in 16.04, but in 18.04, the only additional drivers I'm offered is for my Nvidia graphics card (M5000M) which I do have selected and works perfectly well.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions about how to get my WiFi working again.

Comment: Where is `rfkill list all`? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, I just added it.

Comment: Not sure if this would help but I have similar setup and here's the combination that works without any issues:  Dual band wireless AC 8265 with kernel 4.15.0-24 and nvidia 390. This is on Lenovo Yoga 720 15". All software from Ubuntu repo without any modification.

Comment: A little bit more info about my wifi, driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-24-generic firmware=34.0.1

Comment: Thanks chili555 for taking the time to help out. I've discovered that it has something to do with Gnome dying at startup which requires me to login twice. The second time I login, the wifi is always disabled. I further discovered that if I leave my laptop lid open while booting in the docking station, Gnome doesn't die and the WiFi works. Weird. But that's life with Linux. You have to tolerate the quirks to get the perks (that rhyme was unintentional!).